# using shared memory in cuda gives memory write error

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have a kernel which works fine as

```
__global__ static void  CalcSTLDistance_Kernel(Integer ComputeParticleNumber)
{
    const Integer TID = CudaGetTargetID();
    const Integer ID  = TID;
    if(ID >= ComputeParticleNumber)
    {
        return ;
    }
    CDistance NearestDistance;
    Integer NearestID = -1;
    NearestDistance.Magnitude = 1e8;
    NearestDistance.Direction = make_Scalar3(0,0,0);
    if(c_daOutputParticleID[ID] < -1)
    {
        c_daSTLDistance[ID] = NearestDistance;
        c_daSTLID[ID] = NearestID;
        return;
    }
    Scalar3 TargetPosition = c_daParticlePosition[ID];

    Integer TriangleID;     
    Integer CIDX, CIDY, CIDZ;
    Integer CID = GetCellID(&CONSTANT_BOUNDINGBOX,&TargetPosition,CIDX, CIDY, CIDZ);
    Integer Range = 1;
    if(CID >=0 && CID < c_CellNum)
    {
        for(Integer k = -Range; k <= Range; ++k)
        {
            for(Integer j = -Range; j <= Range; ++j)
            {
                for(Integer i = -Range; i <= Range; ++i)
                {
                    Integer MCID = GetCellID(&CONSTANT_BOUNDINGBOX,CIDX +i, CIDY + j,CIDZ + k);
                    if(MCID < 0 || MCID >= c_CellNum)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    unsigned int TriangleNum = c_daCell[MCID].m_TriangleNum;
                    for(unsigned int l = 0; l < TriangleNum; ++l)
                    {
                        TriangleID = c_daCell[MCID].m_TriangleID[l];
                        if( TriangleID >= 0 && TriangleID < c_TriangleNum && TriangleID != NearestID)// No need to calculate again for the same triangle
                        {
                            CDistance Distance ;
                            Distance.Magnitude = CalcDistance(&c_daTriangles[TriangleID], &TargetPosition, &Distance.Direction);
                            if(Distance.Magnitude < NearestDistance.Magnitude)
                            {
                                NearestDistance = Distance;
                                NearestID = TriangleID;
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    c_daSTLDistance[ID] = NearestDistance;
    c_daSTLID[ID] = NearestID;
}
```

here `c_daParticlePosition` is of `float3` data type and resides in constant memory. I want to use shared memory so I tried to create a `float3` variable in shared memory and tried to copy the data from constant memory to shared memory. However, it shows unknown error and with `cuda-memcheck` it says

```
here thread number is 255 with 2 block size
```

**Shared memory code:**

```
__global__ static void CalcSTLDistance_Kernel(Integer ComputeParticleNumber)
{
    //const Integer TID = CudaGetTargetID();
    const Integer ID  =CudaGetTargetID(); 
    extern __shared__ float3 s[];
    /*if(ID >= ComputeParticleNumber)
    {
        return ;
    }*/
    s[ID] = c_daParticlePosition[ID];
    __syncthreads();

    CDistance NearestDistance;
    Integer NearestID = -1;
    NearestDistance.Magnitude = 1e8;
    NearestDistance.Direction.x = 0;
    NearestDistance.Direction.y = 0;
    NearestDistance.Direction.z = 0;//make_Scalar3(0,0,0);
    //if(c_daOutputParticleID[ID] < -1)
    //{
    //  c_daSTLDistance[ID] = NearestDistance;
    //  c_daSTLID[ID] = NearestID;
    //  return;
    //}

    //Scalar3 TargetPosition = c_daParticlePosition[ID];

    Integer TriangleID;     
    Integer CIDX, CIDY, CIDZ;
    Integer CID = GetCellID(&CONSTANT_BOUNDINGBOX,&s[ID],CIDX, CIDY, CIDZ);
    if(CID >=0 && CID < c_CellNum)
    {
        //Integer Range = 1;
        for(Integer k = -1; k <= 1; ++k)
        {
            for(Integer j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
            {
                for(Integer i = -1; i <= 1; ++i)
                {
                    Integer MCID = GetCellID(&CONSTANT_BOUNDINGBOX,CIDX +i, CIDY + j,CIDZ + k);
                    if(MCID < 0 || MCID >= c_CellNum)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    unsigned int TriangleNum = c_daCell[MCID].m_TriangleNum;
                    for(unsigned int l = 0; l < TriangleNum; ++l)
                    {
                        TriangleID = c_daCell[MCID].m_TriangleID[l];
                        /*if(c_daTrianglesParameters[c_daTriangles[TriangleID].ModelIDNumber].isDrag)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }*/

                        if( TriangleID >= 0 && TriangleID < c_TriangleNum && TriangleID != NearestID)// No need to calculate again for the same triangle
                        {
                        CDistance Distance ;
                            Distance.Magnitude = CalcDistance(&c_daTriangles[TriangleID], &s[ID], &Distance.Direction);
                            if(Distance.Magnitude < NearestDistance.Magnitude)
                            {
                                NearestDistance = Distance;
                                NearestID = TriangleID;
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    c_daSTLDistance[ID] = NearestDistance;
    c_daSTLID[ID] = NearestID;
}
```

**error**

```
  Invalid __shared__ write of size 4
    =========     at 0x00000128 in CalcSTLDistance_Kernel(int)
    =========     by thread (159,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
    =========     Address 0x0000077c is out of bounds
```

Comment: last code is the present code which gives error and the shared memory size is default. I am using GTX 750 Ti which is compute capability 5.0

Answer (score 4):

You may find useful info on how to work with shared memory in [this article](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/). Focus especially on **static shared memory** and **dynamic shared memory** sections.

Based on above article you should find out that you are simply writing out of bounds of your array `s`, exactly as the error message says. To fix the issue you can:

- either specify the size of shared memory array `s` at compile time,
  if you know it in advance, such as `__shared__ float3 s[123456];`
- or use dynamically sized `s` array, thats basically what you are doing at the moment, but **ALSO** specify the third kernel launch parameter as `CalcSTLDistance_Kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize, sharedMemorySizeInBytes>>>`. In case you will be using an array of `123456` `float3`s then use `int sharedMemorySizeInBytes = 123456 * sizeof(float3)`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that the third kernel launch parameter needed to be the size in bytes. In my research, no one else mentioned this little detail, and I had incorrectly assumed it was the number of elements.